# Fitting objects in window screen using Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, mobileemulation

I am trying to fit all the objects in the window (Chrome browser). Manually when I am doing it(the dimensions that I am using is 1024X786 using toggle bar, but when I am automating it using the same dimension, it's not showing the same as it was manually.

The following is the code:

```
driver = new ChromeDriver();
Map<String, Object> deviceMetrics = new HashMap<String, Object>();
deviceMetrics.put("width", 768);
deviceMetrics.put("height", 1024);
Map<String, Object> mobileEmulation = new HashMap<String, Object>();
mobileEmulation.put("deviceMetrics", deviceMetrics);
mobileEmulation.put("userAgent", "Mobile S");
Map<String, Object> chromeOptions = new HashMap<String, Object>();
chromeOptions.put("mobileEmulation", mobileEmulation);
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptions);
System.out.println("Driver is now ChromeDriver");
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

The footer is getting lost in this. What I am getting is: 
[image]

What I am suppose to get is this:
[image]

Another code I used is:

```
driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1024, 786));
```

Can anyone please help? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Setting the size of the window wont work if you want to fit contents of a web page in window without scroll If it's a large page.

What you will have to do is adjust the zoom level to fit all contents in window.

You can do this as shown below:

```
WebElement html = driver.findElement(By.tagName("html"));
html.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.SUBTRACT));
```

Make sure to reset the zoom level afterwards as shown below:

```
html.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "0"));
```

What basically happens here is the same as what happens when you press **Control** and **-** in your keyboard while focusing on your browser.

Try it out, if this serves your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the `mobileEmulation` related configuration within an instance of `ChromeOptions` Class as follows:

```
Map<String, Object> deviceMetrics = new HashMap<>();
deviceMetrics.put("width", 768);
deviceMetrics.put("height", 1024);

Map<String, Object> mobileEmulation = new HashMap<>();
mobileEmulation.put("deviceMetrics", deviceMetrics);
mobileEmulation.put("userAgent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.2.1; en-us; Nexus 5 Build/JOP40D) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.166 Mobile Safari/535.19");

ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("mobileEmulation", mobileEmulation);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

Note: Testing a mobile website on a desktop using mobile emulation can be useful, but testers should be aware that there are many subtle differences such as:

- Entirely different GPU, which may lead to big performance changes;
- Mobile UI is not emulated (in particular, the hiding url bar affects page height);
- Disambiguation popup (where you select one of a few touch targets) is not supported;
- Many hardware APIs (for example, orientationchange event) are unavailable.

### Reference

[Mobile Emulation](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/mobile-emulation)

### tl; dr

Mobile Emulation is subject to a known issue [Test testClickElement from MobileEmulationCapabilityTest class fails on Chromium for all platforms](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=2144&desc=2)