# Testing webpage using selenium on PC, Iphone and Ipad

Tags: c#, selenium, ipad

I have a requirement to test a webpage using chrome browser on various devices like pc, iphone and ipad to verify the orientation and display of various UI elements.

I'm able to view the display and orientation using the developer tools in chrome on my pc for various mobile devices.

However I wanted to know if I can test this by launching the chrome browser using selenium and c# to resize the window as per the resolution of ipad in chrome developer tools.

Would this be a reliable way to test?

```
 driver.Manage().Window.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(320, 568);
```

Comment: Have tried chrome options to set the window size.

Answer (score 0):

To resize the *Chrome Browser* window you can use either of the following options:

- Using *IWindow Interface*:

  ```
  driver.Manage().Window.Size = new Size(1024, 768);
  ```
- Using *ChromeOptions* and `AddArgument()`    :

  ```
  ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
  chromeOptions.AddArgument("--window-size=1024,768");
  IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions)
  ```
- Using `ExecuteScript()`:

  ```
  ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("window.resizeTo(1024, 768);");
  ```

You can find a *Java* based relevant solution in [Fitting objects in window screen using Selenium Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54655760/fitting-objects-in-window-screen-using-selenium-java/54667711#54667711)